# I want to use remove pattern to remove user(@), on tweet data in Jupyter. After I run why the error appears

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to use remove pattern to remove user(@), on tweet data. After I run why the error appears. My code is like this

```
def remove_pattern(input_txt, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern, input_txt)
    for i in r:
        input_txt = re.sub(i, '', input_txt)
    return input_txt    
df['remove_user'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(df['text'], "@[\w]*")
```

I have changed it to string format, even user(@) is not deleted

```
def remove_pattern(Tweet, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern, str(Tweet))
    for i in r:
        input_txt = re.sub(i, '', str(Tweet))
    return Tweet
df['remove_user'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(df['Tweet'], "@[\w]*")
```

Comment: You mean you'd like to remove substrings such as '@John' or '@User123' ?

Comment: Yes sir. I want remove it form my datatwet.csv which there are already hundreds of tweets

Comment: You could do something like `df["Tweet"].str.replace(r"@\w*", "", regex=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need regex for this case, you could use a nested list comprehension as well, which might be faster. Let's suppose the column with the tweets is `df['Tweets']`.

```
df['Tweets'] = [' '.join([y for y in x.split() if not y.startswith("@")]) for x in df['Tweets'].fillna("")]
```

With this sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Tweets":['Hello @John how are you?',"Is this @TheReal user?"]})
```

It outputs:

```
               Tweets
0  Hello how are you?
1       Is this user?
```

Comment: still can't sir, and an error like this appears "
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"


Maybe I can use regex, it's just that I'm stuck

Comment: Ah, you are getting that because at least one of your rows are null. Please check the edit.